# Let's Encrypt ssl certificate send twice in TLS handshake

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt

when making a wireshark trace to check if my Let's Encrypt certificate is correctly offered by our server, I see that the same certificate is being send twice in TLS handshake when 'Server Hello Done'.

How can this occur ? How to correct ?

[image]

The certificate details is 2 times exactly the same :

[image]

Extra info requested :
I trace this with wireshark by visiting a https-page of my Apache webserver (CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)) with my Chrome browser on Fedora 25 client.

VirtualHost config :

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.tld/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.tld/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.tld/fullchain.pem
```

Don't know if it matters, but I also have a second VirtualHost with a different Let's Encrypt certificate :

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my2.domain.tld/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my2.domain.tld/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my2.domain.tld/fullchain.pem
```

Comment: You have blanked out the certificate names. Are you sure that the exact certificate is being sent twice or that the certificate chain is being sent?

Comment: I added an extra screenshot. The details is 2 times exactly the same. The domain name that I blurred is also 2 times the same.

Comment: The certificate serial numbers are identical. I do a lot of wire traces for SSL issues but I have never paid attention to this one. Check your certificate chain file to see if your SSL certificate is part of the certificate chain file. You will probably find your cert is at the top. The actual configuration of your cert, chain and key depends on the software using the certificate which you did not mention.

Comment: You are not providing a lot of details: what is the client? what TLS libraries does it use? Who is the server? Do you have the same behaviour if you change the client or the server or the certificate? You are on a site devote to programming, so without any program to show you are offtopic here and should look probably more at [sf].

Comment: I've added extra info on client and server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Problem

---

This is caused by simultaneous config of `SSLCertificateFile` along with `SSLCertificateChainFile`.

From [the mod_ssl documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile) (Emphasis mine):

> This directive sets the optional all-in-one file where you can assemble the certificates of Certification Authorities (CA) which form the certificate chain of the server certificate. **This starts with the issuing CA certificate of the server certificate** and can range up to the root CA certificate.

But if you check your `fullchain.pem`, you'll see that it includes the **server** certificate at the top, followed by the Let's Encrypt issuing CA. Apache is delivering the contents of `SSLCertificateFile` with the `SSLCertificateChainFile` concatenated after it. Since your server's certificate appears in both of them, it's duplicated in the final chain seen in the SSL handshake, just like you observed in Wireshark:

```
   vhost.conf                   Sent To Client 
+---------------+            +------------------+
|   cert.pem    |----------> |Server Certificate|
|               |            |        +         |
|       +       |      +---> |Server Certificate|
|               |      |     |        +         |
| fullchain.pem |----------> | CA Certificate   |
+---------------+            +------------------+
```

### The Fix

---

In modern Apache, don't use `SSLCertificateChainFile` directive anymore, and give `fullchain.pem` directly to `SSLCertificateFile`.

Again, from [the mod_ssl documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile):

> **SSLCertificateChainFile is deprecated**
>
> `SSLCertificateChainFile` became obsolete with version 2.4.8, when [SSLCertificateFile](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatefile) was extended to also load intermediate CA certificates from the server certificate file.

So all you should need to do is change your vhost configuration from this:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.tld/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.tld/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.tld/fullchain.pem
```

To this:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.tld/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.tld/privkey.pem
```